# How do you create a custom css pop-up to open on page load once per visitor per week

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Okay I have the below code, which will allow me to either click the link or hover over the link to show the pop-up.  I would like to be able to edit it to make it open on page load.  I would also like to be able to have it open only once per visitor per week.

I am new to this so any help would be great!

Thanks

```
    <head>

<style type="text/css">
#fade {
    display: none;
    background: #000; 
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: .80;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block{
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px;     
    border: 20px solid #ddd;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
img.btn_close {
    float: right; 
    margin: -55px -55px 0 0;
}
.popup p {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
/*--Making IE6 Understand Fixed Positioning--*/
*html #fade {
    position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#?w=200" rel="popup1" class="poplight">Hover to see pop-up</a>

<div id="popup1" class="popup_block">
TEST    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').hover(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/modal-window/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

        return false;
    });


    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
          $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
    }); //fade them both out

        return false;
    });


});

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to include in the user table the last time they were shown the popup. Then whenever a user first visits the site (or logs in) check the current timestamp against the last popup timestamp. If its been a week show the popup and update the users popup timestamp to the current timestamp.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that could you explain a little more or show me some sample code?

Comment: you will have to know some server-side language. What server side language do you know?